# assign array values to a range in excel spsh

Tags: excel, vba

I have defined an array, populated it, and am attempting to set a range in an excel spsh equal to it.  When I use the simple code below (I've left out the value assignments), I get the array value subscript 1 in every cell of the range.  Can anyone see what's wrong?  Thanks.

```
Dim Loss(1 To 10000)

Range("Losses!u11:u10010") = Loss
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel ranges are always two dimensional

```
Public Sub foo()
  Dim Loss(1 To 10000, 1 To 1)

  For i = 1 To 10000
    Loss(i, 1) = i
  Next

  Range("Losses!u11:u10010") = Loss
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a limit to how large an array can be put on the sheet with this?  The very same code with a dimension of 400,000 doesn't seem to work.  Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Excel 2003 has a row limit of 65536, so 400000 would not fit. For versions (2007+) with enough rows, you'll need to make sure the dimensions of the destination range match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately:

```
Range("Losses!u11:u10010").Value = Application.Transpose(Loss)
```